# Responsive mobile menu opening issue when I turn my device horizontally

Tags: html, css, mobile, menu

I made a responsive menu for mobiles, but when I turn my device horizontally **the menu opens immediately** and I can't scroll on it. The only way is putting the phone back on portrait position. Please help! I'm new to this.

The website is [www.josefinaechenique.com](http://www.josefinaechenique.com)

Code down below:

**HTML**

```
 <!--menu mobile-->
 <nav id="navigation_mobile">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html" onclick="location.replace('index.html')">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="biografia.html" onclick="location.replace('biografia.html')">Biografía</a></li>
    <li><a href="musica.html" onclick="location.replace('musica.html')">Música</a></li>
    <li><a href="videos.html" onclick="location.replace('videos.html')">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="conciertos.html" onclick="location.replace('conciertos.html')">Conciertos</a></li>
    <li><a href="contacto.html" onclick="location.replace('contacto.html')">Contacto</a></li>

<div class="social_icons2">
<a href="musica.html" onclick="window.open('https://www.instagram.com/lajoseoficial/')"><img src="img/insta_logo.png" width="17" height="17" alt=""/></a> 
<a href="musica.html" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/lajoseoficial/')"><img src="img/fb_logo.png" width="17" height="17" alt=""/></a>
<a href="musica.html" onclick="window.open('https://www.youtube.com/user/proserfina/')"><img src="img/youtube_logo.png" width="17" height="17" alt=""/></a>
 </div>
  </ul>
</nav>

<!--button toggle-->
<div class="menu_bar">
    <p class="bt-menu"><span class="icon-list2">   
</span>Josefina<br>Echenique</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#navigation_mobile {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  top: -100%;
  margin-top: 66px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: #323034;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

#navigation_mobile ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#navigation_mobile ul li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0, .15);
  padding: 12px;
}

.menu_bar {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: #323034;
  position: fixed;
  box-shadow: 20px 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

**JS**

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(main);

var contador = 1 ;

function main (){
$('.menu_bar').click(function(){
    if(contador == 1){
        $('nav').animate({
            top: '0'
        });

        contador = 0;
    } else {
        contador = 1;
        $('nav').animate({
            top: '-100%'
        });

    }

});


}
```

Here is a picture of the problem.

horizontal posisiton (wrong)
[image: Figure 3]

Comment: You need to use css media queries.

Comment: @jack excuse my ignorance, but is that the same as making a javascript file or not? I made the menu with a tutorial and it included a .js document (i'll add it to the post). Thanks

Comment: You can do it with JS, but it's better using CSS for many reasons. Just google css media queries, see some examples and it'll be easy.

Comment: media queries in css are like using `if`s in code. The stuff inside a media query tag is just css.

Comment: @jack Did you even look at the page? It is already using media queries. That would be the part in the style.css file that says `@media screen and (max-width : 800px ) { ... }`

Comment: Ofc, but I think she doesn't know.

Comment: Perhaps that may be the case, but how is the problem she is having caused by a lack of media queries, and how can it be fixed by adding a new media query? Also, can you explain why the problem doesn't appear on desktop browsers in mobile preview mode, but it does occur in mobile browsers like mobile Safari?

Comment: I do have one media query but without orientation specification. Could be that? Should I be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be happening because the `.menu_bar` and `#navigation_mobile` style rules have the same z-index, but I'm not 100% sure that is the issue.  You could try reducing the z-index on `#navigation_mobile` and see if that works.

If that does not work, this will probably fix your problem:

Edit the CSS stylesheet to remove `margin-top: 66px` from `#navigation_mobile`. Then edit your Javascript as follows:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(main);

var contador = 1 ;

function main (){
$('.menu_bar').click(function(){
    if(contador == 1){
        $('nav').animate({
            top: '66px'
        });

        contador = 0;
    } else {
        contador = 1;
        $('nav').animate({
            top: '-100%'
        });

    }

});


}
```

Comment: Thanks! I used both solutions. First solved the problem of the opening, but the sections where overlapping behind, so the next solution fixed that. But I still cannot scroll on it when the device is horizontal. @blendenzo

Comment: @Margaret : That is because you are using `position: fixed;` on `#navigation_mobile`.  Try using `position: absolute;` instead. Keep in mind that `position: absolute;` can be affected by the parent element. So if `#navigation_mobile` is wrapped in a `<div>` which has a `position: relative;`, the absolute position will be calculated with the top-left corner of the parent `<div>` being (0, 0). I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, that's what happened. If I open the menu when I've already scrolled down, it opens in the (0,0) position. Should I change the relative position as well from the parent element? @blendenzo